# Howto install ActiveMQ Artemis Console on Karaf Osgi

Tags: apache-karaf, activemq-artemis

I installed the artemis feature in Karaf 4.2.9. The broker is well created. I see it in jmx.

But I can't find how to install the Artemis web console in Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a feature for the ActiveMQ Artemis web console for Karaf to install.

Comment: Thank

I will try to install the war.

I think he will miss the config.

Comment: What config do you mean?

Comment: the config of webconsole

Comment: What config of the webconsole will be missed if you just install the war?

Comment: Thank for all.
I don't have time now. but monday. ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create own repository with feature for for artemis console.

1. This feature includes 3 bundles: artemis-console.war, artemis-plugin.war, activemq-branding.war
2. artemis-console.war still (2.32.0) has version 1 manifest, so your feature must wrap it and include the necessary details. At least - Web-ContextPath (**/console** in this example) and Bundle-ClassPath.

This is my template:

```xml
<feature name="artemis-console" version="${artemis.version}">
    <feature prerequisite="true">wrap</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-plugin/${artemis.version}/war</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-branding/${artemis.version}/war</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-console/${artemis.version}/war$Bundle-SymbolicName=ActiveMQ Artemis Console&amp;Bundle-Version=${artemis.version}&amp;Web-ContextPath=/console&amp;Bundle-ClassPath=.,WEB-INF/classes,${artemis.embedded.list}</bundle>
</feature>
```

As you can see, this template includes placeholders ${artemis.version} and ${artemis.embedded.list}. ${artemis.embedded.list} must include all embedded jars in this artemis-console bundle. You can list them manually, but i've made maven project, so i can easily change artemis version:

1. this project has 1 dependency (artemis-console), and it has to be downloaded (into target/lib) to read embedded file list
2. I placed the template in filtered resources - so maven will change placeholders to property values
3. I used maven-antrun-plugin to read embedded files list and export it into project property
   This is full maven project snippet:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.own.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-features</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-console</artifactId>
            <version>${artemis.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/main/feature</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>custom-features.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>artemis-console</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                            <target>
                                <macrodef name="listzipcontents">
                                    <attribute name="zipfile" />
                                    <attribute name="property" />
                                    <attribute name="prefix" />
                                    <sequential>
                                        <zipfileset src="@{zipfile}" id="content" includes="@{prefix}/*"/>
                                        <pathconvert property="@{property}" pathsep="," dirsep="/">
                                            <zipfileset refid="content" />
                                            <map from="@{zipfile}:" to="" />
                                        </pathconvert>
                                    </sequential>
                                </macrodef>
                                <listzipcontents zipfile="${basedir}/target/lib/artemis-console-${artemis.version}.war"
                                    property="artemis.embedded.list" prefix="WEB-INF/lib" />
                                <echo>${artemis.embedded.list}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As result - this feature for artemis-console 2.32.0, including long embedded jar list:

```xml
<feature name="artemis-console" version="2.32.0">
    <feature prerequisite="true">wrap</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-plugin/2.32.0/war</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-branding/2.32.0/war</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-console/2.32.0/war$Bundle-SymbolicName=ActiveMQ Artemis Console&amp;Bundle-Version=2.32.0&amp;Web-ContextPath=/console&amp;Bundle-ClassPath=.,WEB-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib/checker-qual-3.33.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.15.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.11.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/guava-32.0.1-jre.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hawtio-core-2.17.7.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hawtio-system-2.17.7.jar,WEB-INF/lib/hawtio-util-2.17.7.jar,WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.5.14.jar,WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.16.jar,WEB-INF/lib/j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jolokia-core-1.7.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/json-20231013.jar,WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-3.0.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar</bundle>
</feature>
```